# How can I create a custom module that can be reinstalled without throwing an error?

Tags: 8, installation

I'm creating a custom module based off of [Bootstrap Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_paragraphs), with a bunch of configuration files for custom paragraph types.
The configuration includes a bunch of `field.storage.` files, which AFAICT result in tables being created in the underlying MySQL data store for the respective fields.

The module is under active development, and I often need to reinstall it to pick up new changes.
Whenever I uninstall it and install it again, I get the error

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: "'field_config' entity with ID 'paragraph.custom_component.custom_component_field' already exists." at /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php line 425, referer: http://localhost:2345/admin/modules.

My best interpretation of this error is that the MySQL store already contains this table, so it can't be created.
Sure enough, when I access MySQL, the tables are there, even after module uninstallation.
Elsewhere, I've seen people say that in Drupal 8 uninstalling a module should cause all traces of the module to be removed, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me.

How can I set up my component so that it will delete the fields from the store when I uninstall it? Is there a better approach I should consider?

#### What I've tried

- Overriding `hook_uninstall()` in the module file and adding the following code

  ```
  \Drupal::configFactory()
    ->getEditable('field.storage.custom_component.custom_component_field')
    ->delete();
  ```
- Renaming the config/install directory to config/optional
- Purging configuration using the "Purge Configuration" tab available from the [Easy Install module](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your config dependent on the module by adding this to the relevant config file(s):

```
dependencies: 
  enforced: 
    module: 
      - module_name
```

When your module is uninstalled, the config will go with it. You probably want to delete any content and field instances in `hook_uninstall` as well.